# scanf("%s",input) doesnt work correctly

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to interface my Nokia N95 with Proteus. It works almost fine, except of one thing. When I want to get the response from the modem, I use `unsigned char input[20]` and `scanf("%s",input)`. When the modem receives a call, it send `RING` to the port, but what I get with `scanf` is `RIG` or `RNG`. What might be the problem?

```
#include <regx51.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


sbit TE = P2^4;//for transmitting
unsigned char ch;
unsigned char ch2;

long i;
short bakar=0;

unsigned char Command_AT[]="AT\r";

unsigned char xdata Command_CPIN[]="AT+CPIN =\"0000\"\r"; 

unsigned char Command_CMGF[]="AT+CMGF=1\r"; 

unsigned char Command_CMGS[]="AT+CMGS =\"5555\"\r"; 

unsigned char msg_report[]="Ok";

unsigned char CtrlZ=0x1A;                   

unsigned char xdata Status_Ok[]="AT\rOK";

unsigned char Command_CHUP[]="AT+CHUP\r";

unsigned char input[10];


void iniSerial()
{
    TMOD=0x20;  
    TH1=0XFD;
    SCON=0x50;
    TR1=1;
    TI=1;
    RI=0;
}
void delay() 
{
    for(i=1;i<=30000;i++); //Dont know how much exactly
}
void delay2()
{
    for(i=1;i<=50000;i++);
}
void sendDeliveryReport() 
{

    puts(Command_AT);
    delay();
    puts(Command_CMGF);
    delay();
    puts(Command_CMGS);
    delay();
    puts(msg_report);
    while(TI == 0);
    SBUF = 0x1A;
}
void checkRing()
{
    while(bakar!=1)
    {
        scanf("%s",&input);//problem is here

        if(strcmp(input,"RING") == 0)
        {
            bakar=1;
            delay();
            puts(Command_CHUP);
        }
        delay2();               
    }
}
void main()
{
    delay2();   //Wait for GSM modem to start.
    TE=1;       //Don't trasmit yet
    iniSerial();
    checkRing();
    TE=0;
    iniSerial();
    sendDeliveryReport();
    while(1);   //Pause forever
}
```

Comment: probably not a scanf issue.  maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Do other characters drop randomly? This is a bizarre issue to have over USB.

Comment: Try to use `fread(&input[0], sizeof(input), 1, stdin);` instead, `input` is data.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, will try. I have added the code, maybe it will help to solve the problem.

Comment: The input is always "RNG" or "RIG"

Comment: I suspect it is a hardware error. What happens if you get overrun errors, framing errors etc? Will the API underneath scanf simply discard them silently? You should check the return value of scanf: `if(scanf("%s", input)==EOF) { /*error */ }`. In general it seems odd to me that you use scanf on a system where you are obviously very close to the bare bone hardware. Why can't you simply read the serial data buffer manually, byte by byte? (I assume this is UART or SPI).

Comment: I can, but I would like to learn how to do it with a function...

Answer (score 6):

Does that code really compile? The if-statement in void checkRing() has mismatched paranthesis.

ps. Sorry for the "answer" instead of a comment, but my reputation does not allow comments.

Comment: Useful content and a little help to get you that privilege => +1 ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your line

```
scanf("%s",&input);
```

is simply wrong. A good compiler should have told you if you have decent warning level.

`&input` is of type `unsigned char (*)[10]`, that is a pointer to a `unsigned char` array. Use

```
scanf("%s",input);
```

instead. Here `input` decays to a `unsigned char*`, which is about what you want **if** what you expect is really a string and not arbitrary data. If your data may contain 0 bytes, you'd have to use `read` or something equivalent.

*Edit:* If your input is really a string use `char` instead of `unsigned char`.

Comment: tried both removing the '&' and removing the 'unsigned', but the input remained the same

Comment: Then look for the second part of my answer. Do you really expect a string or is this arbitrary binary data? If the later, `scanf` is not at all what you should use.

Comment: In this case, `&input` and `input` are exactly the same. An array's address is the same as the address of the first element.

Comment: @ugoren, the values are the same, the types not.

Comment: @JensGustedt, Right, but `scanf` gets the value, not the type, so behaviour here is the same.

Answer (score 2):

I must say that this code seems to invite a hacker attack.

The line `scanf("%s",&input);` reads bytes until a newline, into the buffer on the stack. If more than 10 bytes are read, the buffer overflows and the stack is corrupted.
From there, the way to overwriting the return address and executing arbitrary code is short.

You must either use `fgets`, which allows you to limit the number of bytes read, followed by `fscanf` to stop at a delimiter, or use, as Daniel Fischer suggested, the format string `"%9s"` which won't store more than 10 bytes in the buffer (9 + terminating null).

Comment: `scanf("%9s", input)` also avoids a buffer overrun.

Comment: @DanielFischer, indeed. But you can't make `9` depend on the actual size of `input`.

Comment: True, but `fscanf` has the same restriction that you can only use literals for the field width. Did you actually mean the `fgets/sscanf` combo?

Comment: @DanielFischer, `fscanf` really is no help. I mixed it up with `gets` and `fgets`, where `fgets` an extra size parameter. `fscanf` doesn't.